# How to use gulp to inject a dynamic timestamp on each build

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp

I am trying to use gulp to inject a timestamp into my html on build. I am using Angular 7. This timestamp should be dynamic and change based on each build. Currently, I have:

timestamp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toString());
var string = d.toString();

gulp.src('src/app/shared/footer/*.html')
  .pipe(replace('GULPTIMESTAMP',string))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/app/shared/footer/'));
```

This takes all html files in the footer folder (which is just one html file) and replaces all instances of GULPTIMESTAMP with the current timestamp. However, my problem is that once it is replaced, I cannot run the timestamp.js file again since GULPTIMESTAMP is already replaced by the current timestamp. Is there a way to have like a {{timestamp}} variable in my html which is dynamically changed based on each build start?

Thinking about it, maybe I could change it in the typescript file instead of the HTML? Just a thought

EDIT: Decided that editing the typescript file would be better than editing directly to the HTML.

Typescript

```
  timestampBuild: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timestampBuild = 'GULPTIMESTAMP'

  }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="color:red">Last Build Timestamp: {{timestampBuild}}  </div>
```

After running the script, the GULPTIMESTAMP in the ts file should change to the current timestamp. But I run into the same issue where I just want a dynamic name.

Comment: Can you show an example of how and where the `GULPTIMESTAMP` variable is being used before and after replacement.

Comment: @Mark, I edited my response, but In essence the GULPTIMESTAMP in the Typescript file is only being used once.which then it is being replaced by the timestamp.

Comment: I was hoping it would be in an attribute which would be easier to replace automatically - no matter what is in the attribute at the time.  Can you just use a regex in your replace step that looks for both `GULPTIMESTAMP` and an actual timestamp - which should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly replacing your keyword (`GULPTIMESTAMP`), you could search for it and insert your timestamp afterwards. Then you can rerun your script again and always insert the current timestamp. Add a placeholder and a fixed length to be able to replace the old timestamp correctly.

Another option is to use gulp-inject-string for your task: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject-string

The examples should give you enough hints to complete your task.